# Creating an iPhone app + Rails app + Devise Authentication

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, devise, restkit, http-authentication

I currently have a rails app using Devise and I'm able to log in through my browser. I now want to create a native iPhone application that uses this rails app as the backend. What I would like:

- When the user first opens the iOS app, they are presented with a login screen.
- They put they're information in and the app tries to log them in. If successful, it lists the users of the rails app (for now). Otherwise it says incorrect login.
- The user could then click on the user's names and it brings up the user's profiles, etc. The app needs to be able to do all CRUD operations as if they were on the site itself.

Right now I'm using Devise and RestKit for the iPhone app. I enabled http_auth in my rails app and I'm able to set the username/password and get back a response from my /users page (listing my users in JSON).

Rails:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
end

end
```

iPhone (using Restkit):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://192.168.1.105:3000" username:@"xxxx" password:@"xxxx"];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/users.json" delegate:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"error");
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
    NSLog(response.bodyAsString);
}
```

I'm not sure what to do from here or how to approach it.

1. How do I handle the login screen? Okay, I can do a
   'http://localhost:3000' GET using the http basic auth and get a users
   list back, but is that how I should test if the user's credentials
   were inputted correctly? Is there some way to just get a OK or NOT
   OK response back for logging in?
2. Whats the best way for interacting
   with the rails app? Is it okay to do things like GET /users/2 using
   RestKit? Or do I need to build some sort of api? I don't know where
   to start with something like this.

Comment: From a security point of view, you probably don't want to send the user credentials in the clear over http. At the very least send a salted hash of the password and have the server perform the same, compare the results.

Comment: I was planning on using https when actually moving to production. Would that be ok?

Comment: So long as you are completely sure all production traffic is over SSL (https) you should be fine. If you like to wear a belt & suspenders do both, that way if the client redirect to http or something crazy you're still covered.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use basic http auth if you have devise?
With devise you can return auth errors in a json hash, and display it on the login screen.

Build your app in a classic REST way, and it'll be quite comfortable for both web-client and mobile client.

You can also try to use something like Rabl https://github.com/nesquena/rabl for building smart JSON APIs in your Rails app.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "return auth errors in a json hash, and display it on the login screen". I saw a few other people using basic http auth in situations like this. What type of auth setup do you mean?

Comment: I mean a usual Devise authentication